# Only sum rows with specific column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum, pivot

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Index    Measure    Tom    Harry    Mary
0        A          10     5        9
1        B          4      4        8
2        A          11     5        7
3        B          2      3        6
4        A          8      5        5
5        B          4      7        5
6        A          10     5        4
7        B          5      5        3
```

I basically need it to sum the values for each person for the rows where Measure = A. So for Tom, it would be 39, Harry would be 20 & Mary would be 25.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can filter and sum, try df.loc[df['Measure'] == 'A', ['Tom', 'Harry', 'Mary']].sum()

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
used pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Measure'], aggfunc=np.sum)